# django how to get list with foreign key using primary key

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

i have this scenario where each company have more then one car , i have linked the two models :

models.py

```
    class Company(models.Model):
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, primary_key=True, null=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_created=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.company_name

class car(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, null=True, related_name='companyname', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    car_reg = models.CharField(max_length=8, null=True)
    mot6due = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    cut_off = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True)
    notes = models.TextField(null=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.car_reg
```

now i have list of companies listed , but now need to access each company to list separate cars belongs to each company

views.py

```
def dashboard(request):
cars = car.objects.all()
total_cars = cars.count()

context = {'cars': cars, 'total_cars': total_cars}

return render(request, 'cars/dashboard.html', context)


def companyList(requst):
    company_list = Company.objects.all()

    context = {'company_list': company_list}

    return render(requst, 'cars/company_list.html', context)
```

and template.html

```
<tbody>
    {% for company in company_list %}

          <tr>
   <td><a href="{% url 'company-list' ?what here? %}"> {{ company.company_name }}</a></td>

          </tr>

    {% endfor %}
      </tbody>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
{% for company in company_list %}

          <tr>
   <td><a href="{% url 'company-list' ?what here? %}"> {{ company.company_name }}</a></td>

          </tr>
{% for item in  company.car_set.all %}


{% endfor %}{% endfor %}
```

please note, class name start with capital letter, instead of car use Car

at this moment im getting this list :

[image]

and want to click on one of the company to list all the cars details for each company , but dont have idea how to pass ant key

```
<td><a href="{% url 'company-list' ?what here? %}"> {{ company.company_name }}</a></td>
```

Comment: thx for the answer , but i was asking more for , like to using already listed company, to click on one of them and get all cars listed for this company

Comment: have you checked it with data, it should show the company and its cars if any car instances there.

Comment: yes i did , but is not showing any thing, i have updated my question so maybe will be more clear what want to get

Comment: i have list of the company , but need list of cars for each company now